# hexo deploy Error: spawn ENOMEM

Tags: github, hexo

When i execute `hexo deploy` , it always an error!I have tried to delete .deploy_git,but doesn‘t solve this problem.

## Error info

```
[root@ecs hexo]# hexo deploy
INFO  Deploying: git
INFO  Clearing .deploy_git folder...
INFO  Copying files from public folder...
FATAL Something's wrong. Maybe you can find the solution here: http://hexo.io/docs/troubleshooting.html
Error: spawn ENOMEM
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:313:11)
    at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:385:9)
    at spawn (/data/www/hexo/node_modules/.4.0.0@cross-spawn/index.js:17:18)
```

## _config.yml

```
deploy:
  type: git
  repo: git@github.com:vincent927/vincent927.github.io.git
  branch: master
```

## version info

```
[root@ecs hexo]# hexo -v
hexo: 3.2.2
hexo-cli: 1.0.2
os: Linux 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64 linux x64
http_parser: 2.7.0
node: 7.1.0
v8: 5.4.500.36
uv: 1.10.0
zlib: 1.2.8
ares: 1.10.1-DEV
modules: 51
openssl: 1.0.2j
icu: 58.1
unicode: 9.0
cldr: 30.0.2
tz: 2016g
```

**How can i fix this problem?**

Comment: Usually this is related to memory running out.